# SetInterval between two functions JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm generating HTML table using JavaScript objects, I created two functions with different headers:

```
function generateTable(data) {
let newobj = data.filter(function(el) {
        return el.Sens == 'Depart';
    })
    .map(function(obj) {
        return {
            Heure: moment(obj.prevu).format("h:mm"),
            Vol: obj.Numvol,
            Compagnie: 'uploads/' + obj.FileName,
            Destination: obj.AeroD + '  via  ' + obj.AeroA,
            Comptoir: obj.Comptoir.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, ''),
            Porte: obj.porte,
            Infos: obj.etat,
            Enregistrement: obj.active_enregistrement,
        }
    });}
```

Second Function  :

```
function generateArTable(data) {
let newobj = data.filter(function(el) {
        return el.Sens == 'Depart';
    })
    .map(function(obj) {

        return {
            'التوقيت': moment(obj.prevu).format("h:mm"),
            'الرحلة': obj.Numvol,
            'الناقل الجوي': 'uploads/' + obj.FileName,
            'الوجهة': obj.AeroD_ar + ' عبر ' + obj.AeroA_ar,
            'الشباك': obj.Comptoir.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, ''),
            'الباب': obj.porte,
            'معلومات': obj.etat

        }
    });
```

they both generate an HTML table using the same table

```
let table = document.querySelector("#fr_table");
```

I want to a create function which has two parameters N and X:

- N is how many times to execute two functions
- X is interval between execution of the two functions

I have tried these functions:

```
 setTimer0 = setInterval(function() {
    generateArTable(data);
    console.log("first function executed");

}, 3500, (0));

setTimer1 = setInterval(function() {
    generateTable(data);
    console.log("second function executed");

}, 3100, (1));
```

but it's not working as expected for the interval between the two functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N is how many times to execute two functions X is interval between exection of the two functions:

```js
function f1(){console.log(1);}
function f2(){console.log(2);}

function asYouWish(N, X) {
  while(N--){
    f1();
    setTimeout(f2, X);
  }
}
asYouWish(3, 500);
```

N is how many times to execute two functions X is interval between exection of each next function:

```js
function f1(){console.log(1);}
function f2(){console.log(2);}

function asIThinkYouReallyWish(N, X) {
  for(let i = 0; i < N*2; i++) {
    setTimeout(i%2? f2 : f1, i * X);
  }
}
asIThinkYouReallyWish(3, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what i needed :)